# Online colour grading LUTs

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, video, lut

So, I was researching some stuff about colour transforms, and found some companies who sell colour grading LUTs.
They did include with the free samples a set of transforms from a bunch of recording formats to rec709, so that the grading LUT will be applied to a rec709 input.

I wasn't considering buying, but I was wondering how useful these would be. Given the expected pixel output 'x' depends on the transform performed on a given pixel input 'y'. Can we genuinely expect 'x' out for any 'y' put in after the conversion to rec709?

If I have recorded for example, Alexa Log-C or RED Log, can I reasonably expect that my Alexa Log-C or RED Log pixel is the same as someone else's Alexa Log-C or RED Log pixel, to convert to rec709 and from there to an orange(or teal) 'film look' pixel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely nailed it; they are a load of codswallop and rubbish.

The bottom line is that *all* colour transforms are based on a chain of assumptions. The moment **a single assumption** is wrong, or **a single transform** is out of order, the whole stack becomes invalid.

TL;DR is you *can* trust the transforms if you know they are the correct ones and they are / were applied properly. However, I would be at least as skeptical with purchased LUTs as one should be with HDRIs; prepare to be underwhelmed at best, and outright scammed at worst.

Fantastic question and welcome to the forum.

;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer.

I figured it might be something like that. 
If my camera is pointing at my scene and not their scene, and I am using my lighting set up, it's possible my shadow pixel won't match their one so it can be tuned towards 'darker' and 'bluer'(teal-er).

I might get the expected result I paid for, I might get something quite like it, or I might not get what I expected at all.  All this, plus assuming the transforms are properly made and properly applied.

Might be better for me to learn how to do my own colour grading and display transforms.

:)